# How to check and count if a word in a linkedHashset appears in a sentence from an arraylist?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashset, word-count

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I want to be able to check and count if each word from uniqueBagOfWords appears in a sentence for example,

UniqueBagOfWords = [i, like, to, play, tennis, think, football, needs, big, changes]

output would be-

Sentence - i like to play tennis = 1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0

sentence - i like football like = 1,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
        sentences.add("i like to play tennis");
        sentences.add("i think football needs big changes");
        sentences.add("i like football like");

List<String[]> bagOfWords = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for(String str : sentences){
        bagOfWords.add(str.split(" "));

    }
    Set<String> uniqueBagOfWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for(String[] s : bagOfWords){
        for(String ss : s)
            for(String st : ss.split(" "))
                if(!uniqueBagOfWords.contains(st))
                    uniqueBagOfWords.add(st);

    }
```

I have tried this, I know its not right but can't work out where to go from here. Any help would be great!

```
for(String s : sentences){
        for(String ss : s.split(" ")){
            int count= 0;
            for(int loop=0; loop <uniqueBagOfWords.size(); loop++){
            if(uniqueBagOfWords.contains(ss)){
                count +=1;
            }



            }
            System.out.println(ss +" "+ count);
```

Comment: why do you want to use set anyway? you can do it with just arraylist.

Comment: How do you get `1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0` from "I like to play tennis"? Shouldn't there be 5 ones, since "tennis" is in the bag?

Comment: You have a hash set. You don't need to traverse it. Just use `contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think an array is the wrong data structure. A better choice would be simply a map of the counts of each word that is in the bag, which is a one-liner:

```
Map<String, Integer> hits = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
   .filter(uniqueBagOfWords::contains)
   .collect(groupingBy(identity()), counting());
```

This will produce something like:

```
{i=1, like=2, football=1}
```

Which seems a whole lot more straightforward. If you absolutely must have a (sparse) array, you can create that as a separate step.

Answer (score -1):

Here I just made a string array for the bag of words and I put all the sentences into an arraylist. Then I made a comparison to check if the letter at a particular position in the sentence matches the position at the bagOfWords array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] bagOfWords = {"i", "like", "to", "play", "tennis", "think", "football", "needs", "big", "changes"};

    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    sentences.add("i like to play tennis");
    sentences.add("i think football needs big changes");
    sentences.add("i like football");

    for(String s1 : sentences){
        String[] sentenceSplit = splitWords(s1);

        for(int i=0;i<sentenceSplit.length;i++){
            if(sentenceSplit[i].equals(bagOfWords[i])){
                System.out.print("1 ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("0 ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

private static String[] splitWords(String sentence){
    String[] afterSplit = sentence.split(" ");
    return afterSplit;
}
```

Comment: You've turned an *O(N)* problem into an *O(N^2)* problem. You should loop through the *sentence* calling `Set.contains()`, which is *O(1)* in the case of a hash set.

Comment: Even if you use contains, you will have to check whether the word is in the correct position or not. For that I think you will need to break the sentence into words. Or Can you just do it with sets? I'm confused.

Answer (score -1):

Try looping through your hashSet, rather than each word in the sentence. Also, I would use a StringBuilder or something similar for the output. Take a look at the loop below:

```
    for (String s : sentences) {

        StringBuilder numberOfOccurences = new StringBuilder();

        for (String word : uniqueBagOfWords) {
            if (s.contains(word)) {
                numberOfOccurences.append("1,");
            } else {
                numberOfOccurences.append("0,");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(s + " = " + numberOfOccurences);
    }
```

Output:

i like to play tennis = 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,

i think football needs big changes = 1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,

i like football = 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,

Comment: How would I update this code so it would count the number of times a word appears? for example if football appeared in a sentence twice it would print 2. thanks!

Comment: Why would you invert the code and loop through a hash set when it has an *O(1)* `contains()` method?